# Rails 4 actionmailer without template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, email-attachments

I have a problem that complicated here,
I had hours and hours looking at a variety of sources but it does not work out, I was tired and wished there was an answer of my problem

I want to send an email, but here I do not use templates but directly send an email with html format, I use the code below in the mailer

```
mail (to: "email@email.com", subject: email.subject, body:  email.description, bcc: ["email@email.com"], content_type: 'text / html')
```

and the results are going well, no problem. then the problem arises when adding an attachment to the email, like the code below

```
attachments['test.jpg'] = {mime_type: 'application/x-gzip', content: File.read('test.jpg')}
```

email sent but because here I am using content_type: 'text/html', the attached file was displayed as text instead of an attachment link,
I try to eliminate content_type: 'text/html' but the outcome even reverse, its attached files appear but its html content of chaotic mess,
I have tried various alternatives such as using

content_type: 'multipart/alternative', 
content_type: 'multipart/related', 
content_type: 'multipart/mixed'

but all to no avail, only one of which succeeded, between displaying the contents of the html or attached file

My question, is there a way that the content of both html and attached files can appear in the email, and how to add an attachment to the email format without template.

I use rails 4, help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: hope you have seen this http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-attachments

Comment: Use inline attachment : `attachments.inline['yourimage.png'] = File.read(yourpath)`

Comment: in what order are you call the `attachments` and `mail` methods ? IIRC, you need to call `mail` last

Comment: `multipart/mixed` is the right content-type for an email containing a HTML and an attachment, BTW

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def method_name
   attachments.inline['test.jpg'] = File.read('/path/test.jpg')
end
```

Email Template

```
<p>Your content</p>
<%= image_tag attachments['test.jpg'].url, alt: 'Test Photo'%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it like you with using `:body => my_html_part`, but the most secure way is to
say: `@content = my_html_part` 
and use the most simple template:
views/my_mailer_name/my_mail_function_name.html.erb:

```
<%= @content %>
```

By adding a second one: views/my_mailer_name/my_mail_function_name.text.erb:

```
Please use the HTML-view:
<% @content=strip_tags(@content) %>
<%= @content %>
```

You get a well formated HMTL-email with all you need.